# How to move Grid Resources to theme file (UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have a Grid like this

```
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12px"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontStretch" Value="Normal"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#5D58F7"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <uctrl:sr ></uctrl:sr>
                </Grid>
```

Which is working fine. Now I want to move these styles to my theme file. To achieve this I have made something like this.

Inside theme.xaml

```
    <Style x:Key="mystyleinsidethemefile" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12px"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStretch" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#5D58F7"/>
   </Style>
```

Inside my page

```
                    <Grid Height="36" >
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource mystyleinsidethemefile}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <uctrl:sr ></uctrl:sr>
                </Grid>
```

all looks good to me but this throws an error as shown in pic
[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Minimal Answer

Setting mystyleinsidethemefile in Style.BasedOn, you may be able to make it work.

```
<Grid Height="36">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource mystyleinsidethemefile}">

        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <uctrl:sr ></uctrl:sr>
</Grid>
```